# Pagination plus offset

Tags: pagination

In EE3.3, I am currently running a news "latest" page where the most recent article is displayed big. While the following 9 articles are displayed in a smaller 2 column layout.

For ease I used two separate EE Entries tags, and used an Offset="1" parameter on the second. This works fine till I come to use pagination! Pagination does not take into account offset. Annoying, but I could understand why.

Apart from rebuilding using a single tag and loads of queries to identify first, last entries, and so forth, does anyone have any good ideas here?

Answer (score 0):

You could use conditionals with one channel entries call:

```
{if count == "1"}
Show the Latest article
{/if}
{if count > "1"}
show the remaining articles
{/if}
```

Comment: Yes i said apart from using a single tag and loads or queries (conditionals)!!! LOL, but thanks